# Tensorflow. Error in Session.Run when using tf.identity of a list of tf.gather operations

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to get two lists of results. Each list has n elements inside ( and ), then I used stack and concat to group then up and then identity to get a reference to them. I was expecting to get the results as array of arrays for each one. 
<0,?,i> = value0
<1,?,i> = value1
.
.
.
 = value_n

My code is as below:

```
list1 = [<tf.Tensor 'Gather_1:0' shape=(?, 4) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'Gather_2:0' shape=(?, 4) dtype=float32>,.....]
list2 = [<tf.Tensor 'Gather_3:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'Gather_4:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>,.....]
 all_1 = tf.identity(list1, name='all_boxes')
 all_2 = tf.identity(list2, name='all_scores')
#I also tried tf.stack
 all_1 = tf.identity(tf.stack(list1, name='all_boxes'))
 all_2 = tf.identity(tf.stack(list2, name='all_scores'))
#I also tried tf.concat. Got all the results in a single array, not an array of arrays
 all_1 = tf.identity(tf.stack(list1, name='all_boxes'))
 all_2 = tf.identity(tf.stack(list2, name='all_scores'))
```

Model is saved.

In another script, I import the model and all_1 and all_2 are found.

```
net_out = []
net_out.extend([all_1, all_2])
outputs = sess.run(net_out, feed_dict={img_ph: im})

#Also I tried to use each list individually but also got error
outputs = sess.run(all_1, feed_dict={img_ph: im})
outputs = sess.run(all_2, feed_dict={img_ph: im})
```

but I got the error

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shapes of all 
inputs must match: values[0].shape = [0,4] != values[4].shape = [50,4].
```

Why it is trying to allocate the data of the forth element result in the first element of the output array? Should I use a different way such as tf.group, tf.pack, tf.concat or other?

**Note**: If I call them one by one without tf.identity, I get the results without problem but it will be a problem when I export it because the n will change according to the size of my input. I was expecting only have to call one or two reference that encapsulate their values keeping the dimensions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do but the way you use `tf.stack` is wrong in my opinion. You should check the documentation before posting things here

Comment: @Nain Which one do you recommend? I just want to get the results of several tensors in one single array of arrays

Comment: `tf.concat` should work

Comment: @Nain Thank you for your suggestion. tf.concat helped me to get the results but mixed. In my case, in a list, each element represents a class, so if class 1 is found 6 times, I should get a array of 6 items for this class but concat, will outputs all the results for all the classes in a single array and not a array of arrays.